# Show html code of web page when pressing an html button

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Is it possible in html/javascript to return the html code of a page?

I have an html page, and i would like to, by a click on a `input[type=button]`, open the source code of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.location = "view-source:" + window.location.href;
```

That should work fine in Firefox and Chrome. It won't work in Internet Explorer though. Another option is to use the `outerHTML` property:

```
var source = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

And that should work fine in most browsers. To get that open in a new window, you could do something like this:

```
var sourceWindow = window.open();
sourceWindow.document.open('text/plain').write(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea! All I can think of is:

For Chrome: try opening the url "view-source:[original url]" in another tab. Might work.

Or to be fancy, use php or ajax to copy the html into a txt file and link to that? Or display it in a  block or something...

Or tell the user to press ctrl+U?